# HttpRequestData wraps body in { "json" : "" }

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, .net-5

I am trying to set up an .NET 5 Azure Http function that takes a request with a json body and outputs it to the logs.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyProject.Test
{
    public sealed class Function
    {
        [FunctionName("Test")]
        public async Task RunAsync(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequestData requestData,
            FunctionExecutionContext executionContext)
        {
            executionContext.Logger.LogInformation(requestData.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

I post a json body to using Postman

```
{
    "myProperty": "abc123"
}
```

Which outputs

```
{ "json": "{\"myProperty\":\"abc123\"}" }
```

I'm not sure why the function is wrapping the body in `{ "json": "" }`.

Have I set up the function incorrectly? Or is it set up correctly and there is another way I can access the raw body?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I followed an out of date guide for setting up .NET 5 Http Functions. THe official microsoft guide works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide

This requires some of these packages to be added to `.csproj`

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.0.1" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="5.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

And the function now looks like this

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyProject.Test
{
    public sealed class Function
    {
        [Function("Test")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequestData requestData,
            FunctionContext context)
        {
            var myclass = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<MyClass>(requestData.Body);

            context.GetLogger("Test").LogInformation(myclass.MyProperty);

            var response = requestData.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }

        public class MyClass
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("myProperty")]
            public string MyProperty { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

The json body now gets serialized correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Since Body is a Stream, please use StreamReader ReadToEndAsync() for assigning to string:

```
string body = await new StreamReader(requestData.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

then JSON convert if needed:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body);
```